# Priceset fields do not appear on CiviEvent form (field notes do) | Backdrop

Tags: civievent, price-sets, backdrop

Apologies if I am missing something fundamental here - I'm pretty sure I am, but just can't work it out:
I have an event registration form for public. As admin user logged in, form appears fine. As public (no user login/private window) profile fields appear OK. However, priceset fields only show the field notes; field label, input field and price field do not appear.

Details of event form:
- Additional delegate registration in addition to self enabled;
- Simple profile with personal contact information and employer field from Organization
- Relatively detailed Priceset with field notes - all fields enabled for public
- usual Drupal/Backdrop civi permissions enabled for public event forms (profile create, custom data, register for events, view event info, view event participants)
- No payment processor (pay later only - invoices enabled).

CiviCRM 5.17.4
Backdrop 1.14
tested in Firefox and Chrome - same issue.
environment: shared hosting (WebhostUK - Linux Business Cloud Webhosting)

Edit: adding screenshot
[image: side-by-side, admin view on left, public view on right]

Comment: Is there anything in the debugging/backtrace or Backdrop watchdog?

Comment: @Laryn Thanks for checking. Typical console output for a price-set field: Array (10) fields => Array (6)   9 => Array (14)     id => "9"     name => "1st_exhbition_delegate_bundle_inc_tab..."     label => "1st exhbition delegate bundle inc tab..."     html_type => "Text"     is_enter_qty => "1"     help_post => "1st exhibitor delegate bundle include..."     weight => "1"     is_display_amounts => "1"     options_per_line => "1"     is_active => "1"     visibility => "public"     visibility_id => "1"     is_required => "0"     options => Array (0)

Comment: @Laryn will look at BD watchdog later today

Comment: Can you also add a screenshot, maybe? Trying to visualize.

Comment: Thanks, @Laryn. Edited post with side-by-side screenshots.

Comment: @Laryn-CEDC.org - thanks for the time you took to look at this. While the Backdrop/Civi combination is a bit of an experiment, it has a real life application and I wanted to get this up online as soon as I can. I dropped the database tables and reinstalled Civi - success (no real data to lose). All works as expected. On my original installation, my web host system defaulted all tables to iSAM engine. I had them convert to innoDB and perhaps there was a corruption/similar. Happy to say seems to be working fine now. Thanks again for your attention.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

As had no data to speak of in db, dropped tables in Civi db and reinstalled CiviCRM. Replicated form and works as expected.